# False syntax for 'U' .... MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx

What is the problem of this query?

```
SELECT Z.Monatsname, M.Name, P.Produktname, G.Bundesland, U.Umsatzbetrag 
FROM Umsatzdaten U   
JOIN Zeit Z ON U.Mon_ID=Z.Mon_ID 
JOIN Mitarbeiter M ON U.Mitarbeiter_ID=M.Mitarbeiter_ID 
JOIN Produkt P ON U.Produkt_ID=P.Produkt_ID 
JOIN Geografie G ON U.Land_ID=G.Land_ID
WHERE G.Bundesland = 'Sachsen' or G.Bundesland = 'Thüringen'
```

I get the message: false syntax for 'U'
in row 2

Comment: The syntax looks correct to me.  Could you have a bad character in the query?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "MDX"? I'm assuming you're not actually trying to run this through Analysis Services, otherwise some syntax errors are to be expected.

Comment: I can not select a .sql query only MDX, DAX and others. I thought I have to use the .mdx extension.

Comment: okay sorry for this question, thanks